# How to post on Facebook a photo with tags using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asihttprequest

I am posting a photo on Facebook from my iPhone app using the Graph API and ASIFormDataRequest.
Everything works fine (photo is uploaded with the right caption). When I try to add tags, photo is still uploaded but with no tag.

Here is how I prepare the data

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/photos",userID]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addFile:filePath forKey:@"file"];
[request setPostValue:caption forKey:@"message"];
[request setPostValue:fbManager._facebook.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[request setAllowCompressedResponse:NO];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60];

//Add tags
NSMutableArray *tagArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(FacebookTag *aTag in aJob.tags) {
    NSNumber *_cordX=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:((aTag.x/aJob.image.size.width)*100.0)];
    NSNumber *_cordY=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:((aTag.y/aJob.image.size.height)*100.0)];

    NSString *cordX=[_cordX stringValue];
    NSString *cordY=[_cordY stringValue];

    NSMutableDictionary* tag = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                aTag.userId, @"to",
                                cordX, @"x",
                                cordY, @"y",
                                nil];
    [tagArray addObject:tag];
}

NSData *tagData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:tagArray];
NSString* tagString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tagData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setPostValue:tagString forKey:@"tags"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

// Upload photo
...

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   newPhoto, @"picture", nil];

    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params
                                                andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

...

// Response received. Photo upload successful, so add tags
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([request.params objectForKey:@"picture"]) {
        // Get photo ID from result
        NSString* photoId = (NSString*)[result objectForKey:@"id"];  

        NSMutableDictionary* params = nil;
        for (int i = 0; i < [tagsList count]; i++) {
            // tagsList contains user IDs to tag
            NSString* uid = (NSString*)[tagsList objectAtIndex:i]; 
            params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:uid, @"to", 
                      nil];
            NSString* graphUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags", [photoId stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
            [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphUrl 
                            andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

It is using FBGraph API

Comment: Prateek, thanks for your answer: I was using pure Facebook graph API and it worked. But I want to keep uploading photos when app goes to background so I switched to ASIHTTPRequest (facebook delegate methods were not invoked when app in background). That's why I'm using ASIHTTPRequest but as I said before, I'm not able to add tags to a photo with it. Any idea?